# Using the List interface where the type given is an interface to be implemented by a setter method

Tags: java, interface

I'm having an issue with using interfaces here. When I try to set the list "answers" to an ArrayList I get the error:

The method setAnswers(List) in the type QuestionImpl is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList)

To me it seems that I would want to to use interfaces in situations like this so I can specify the implementation later.

```
public class QuestionImpl  extends QuestionAnswerImpl implements Comparable<Object>, Question {
private List<Answer> answers;
public QuestionImpl(){
    setAnswers(new ArrayList<AnswerImpl>());
}
    @Override
public void setAnswers(List<Answer> answers) {
    this.answers = answers;

}
@Override
public List<Answer> getAnswers() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return answers;
}
```

Answer Interface:

```
public interface Answer {
int i=0;
public int compareTo(Object object1);
public String getListValu(int question);
public void setNum(int i);


}

Answer class info (most of the code is irrelevant here)
public class AnswerImpl extends QuestionAnswerImpl implements
    Comparable<Object>, Answer {...}
```

Comment: change to `setAnswers(new ArrayList<Answer>());` (so `<Answer>` rather than `<AnswerImpl>`)

Answer (score 2):

Your type parameter is wrong. Your method expects a list of the type `Answer` but you pass a list of `AnswerImpl` which is not the same. These are two different types. You can fix this by having a generic type parameter e.g.

```
@Override
public void setAnswers(List<? extends Answer> answers) {
    this.answers = answers;
}
```